# Decrease price value

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have TextView in my Android app. It shows price , that parse from JSON.

I convert text value in float like this

```
const float price2 = float.Parse(price.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also I have "plus" and "minus" buttons

Plus button increase price value

```
plus.Click += delegate
{
    counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++count);
    price.Text = string.Format("{0}", count*price2 + "грн");
};
```

How I can decrease value by tapping "minus" button?

I try to make price2 const, but have this error

> SoucesDetails1.cs(25,25):
>   Error CS0133: The expression being assigned to 'price2' must be
>   constant (CS0133)

Comment: ommit the const from `price2` as the value returned by your inout-textbox may change, doesn´t it?

Comment: Does "increase" work correctly?

Comment: Yes , increase works correctly@GoogleHireMe

Comment: yes, you're right@HimBromBeere

Comment: it work's correctly if I write this :   float price2 = float.Parse(price.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); @GoogleHireMe

Comment: So what is the question now? Obviously the error disappeared, didn´t it?

Comment: How I can decrease price value when I tap minus?

I try to make it like this: price2-(price2/count)

It don't work correctly @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you´d have to add another eventHandler to your second button:

```
float price2 = float.Parse(price.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
minus.Click += delegate
{
    counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", --count);
    price.Text = string.Format("{0}", count * price2 + "грн");
};
```